# Is the spin of the transferred 4s electron always opposite to the spin of 3d electron in chromium?

Tags: electrons, electronic-configuration

I am studying atomic structure and found out that Chromium has an exception in electronic configuration. One electron from 4s jumps to 3d to achieve stability.

let's say the spin of transferred electron is +1/2. Then the other 4s electron should have -1/2. Then, are all the 3d electrons of +1/2 spin or some may have -1/2 spin too?

Comment: Hund's rule still applies here.

Comment: @Zhee,but the multiplicity changes,so what would be correct

Comment: Your question is not particularly clear on when you want to make this observation. Immediately? After a long time?

Comment: whenever it becomes stable

Comment: Define "stable".

Comment: I mean until it reaches its ground state electronic configuration

Comment: Didn't you just answer your own question?

Comment: but I have asked that,does the spin cobversion happens when electron from 4s goes into 3d,as to attain max. possible stability?if yes,then how does the spin conversion happens,if no,how can the electron which before had +1/2 in 4s can have -1/2 when it goes to 3d?

Comment: I think spins between different atoms don't necessarily correlate. You'd have to express the new eigenstates as a function of the old eigen states. That already means you may not know what the spin is after transferring the electron... You can learn more about spin flips [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_line).

Comment: @zee,ohhk,but why then the multiplicity of chromium defined,as if we dont know the spin of the electron that jumped,so it may be two different values ?

Comment: It might be in multiple states before collapse of the wave function.

Comment: @Zhe,so,is there still uncertainity regarding multiplicity of chromium?